# NumberFormatException with couchdb apache camel integration

Tags: spring-boot, couchdb, spring-camel

I am trying to connect couchdb from camel in a spring boot application,but getting the below error during application start.

> org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0-g1AAAAFTeJzLYWBg4MhgTmEQTM4vTc5ISXLIyU9OzMnILy7JAUox5bEASYYGIPX____5WYkMBNU-gKj9T4zaAxC19_GrTXIAkknxRJq5AGLmfgJmJoDMrCdoZpICSJ09QXWJDEnyEEVZAMsCby4"

I even created an empty new database and tried connecting it,but getting the same error.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
<artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
<version>2.24.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
<artifactId>camel-couchdb</artifactId>
<version>2.24.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
<artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<version>2.24.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the camel router definition

```
@Component
public class RouterConfig extends RouteBuilder{

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

 from("couchdb:http://127.0.0.1:5984/migration").process(new DocumentProcessor());
}
```

}

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CouchDb 2.3.0 you can be affected by this Lightcouch [issue](https://github.com/lightcouch/LightCouch/issues/73)(Lightcouch is used by camel-couchdb)

purge_seq format changed in version 2.3.0, this attribute is returned when requesting the database information using GET /dbname

Lightcouch can not manage this format change. You need to patch Lightcouch or use the version from a fork that includes the fix, like [this one](https://github.com/IndabaConsultores/LightCouch). You may do it by modifying your pom file.